# Number of times number appears in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I found an exercise in a C++ book that says "Write a function that will count the number of times a number appears in an array.". Everything is fine, the program is working. But the exercise also says that the function should be recursive.

How can I make a recursive function working like this?

```
#include <iostream>

int count(int number, int array[], int length)
{
    int counter = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if(array[i] == number)
            counter++;
    return counter;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[10] = {3,4,1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5};
    int number_to_search = 5;
    std::cout << number_to_search << " appears "
              << count(number_to_search, numbers, 10)
              << " times in the array.";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the loop and counter you have now, return `0 + recursive_step` or `1 + recursive_step`, where `recursive_step` is a call to `count(...)` where you have increased the array pointer and decreased `length`. Your *base case* is when `length == 0`, at which point you just return `0`.

A nice way of understanding recursion is to study how the calculation is carried out, step by step. In your example you will do something like this:

```
count(5, {3,4,1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5})
0+count(5, {4,1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5})
0+0+count(5, {1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5})
0+0+0+count(5, {2,4,5,6,5,4,5})
0+0+0+0+count(5, {4,5,6,5,4,5})
0+0+0+0+0+count(5, {5,6,5,4,5})
0+0+0+0+0+1+count(5, {6,5,4,5})
0+0+0+0+0+1+0+count(5, {5,4,5})
0+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+count(5, {4,5})
0+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+0+count(5, {5})
0+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+0+1+count(5,{})
0+0+0+0+0+1+0+1+0+1+0  <---The last 0 is the base case
3
```

---

If you are allowed to change the function specification, you can do also something cool called *tail recursion*. Instead of `return 1 + count(...)`, add the accumulated number so far as a paremeter to count: `int count(int number, int array[], int length, int acc)`

And do `return count(..., acc+1)` or `return count(..., acc+0)`. Some compilers are then able to do *tail call optimization* , transforming it into a loop in the compiled code. This saves memory compared to a regular recursion.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer :) I'll look up this tail recursion thing :)

Answer (score 5):

Use this `count` function:

```
int count(int number, int array[], int length) {
    if (length == 0) return 0;
    return (number == *array) + count(number, array+1, length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about trying like this:-

```
int count(int num, int* arr, int length) {
    if (!length)
        return 0;
    int c = count(num, arr+1, length-1);
    return arr[0] == num? c + 1: c;
}

int main(void) {
int arr[10] = {3,4,1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5};

std::cout << count(2, arr, 10);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks :D 
this exercise seem to be silly to me. I mean isn't the original solution more effective than this? Or I should use recursive for problems like this?

Comment: The point of this exercise is to practice recursion. There are lots of problem where recursion is much easier to write and understand than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you do (I wouldn't show you any code to avoid spoiling an exercise for you).

First, recall that in order to be recursive your function needs to call itself. Next, consider these two points:

- When the `length` parameter is equal to zero, the return value of `count(...)` must be zero
- When the `length` parameter is not zero, consider the return value of `count(...)` for `array + 1` and `length-1`; let's call it `prior`. The return value of the current `count(...)` will be equal to `prior+1` if `array[0]` is equal to `number`, or to `prior` when `array[0]` is not equal to `number`.

When you make your code out of this description, observe how you have an `if` at the beginning of your recursive function. This `if` splits your code into the base case (`length == 0`) and the recursive step (computing the result based on a recursive call). This is a common structure of recursive functions: you will have to reproduce this structure every time you write recursive code.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

void count(int number, int array[], int length, int &occurence)
{
    if (*array == number) ++occurence;  

    if (length == 1)
        return;
    else    
        count(number, array+1, length-1, occurence);
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[10] = {3,4,1,2,4,5,6,5,4,5};
    int number_to_search = 5;
    int occurence = 0;
    count(number_to_search, numbers, 10,occurence);
    std::cout << number_to_search << " appears "
              << occurence
              << " times in the array.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <ctime>
 #include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;
 int i, j,n,c=0, k=0;
 int a[1000], b[1000];
 class Array {


    public:
        void input ()
        {
            cout<<"Enter how many values: ";
            cin>>n;
        }

        void arraySeries ()
        {
            cout<<"Array elements: ";
            srand(time(0));
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                a[i]=rand()%100+1;
                cout<<a[i]<<" ";

            }
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<"Odd elements of array: ";
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {   
                if(a[i]%2==1)
                {
                    b[i]=a[i];
                    k++;
                    cout<<b[i]<<" ";
                }

            }
        }
        // i want to find out how many times an odd number is found in b[i]
        // but i am not being able to do so. SOMEONE PLEASE HELP!!
        void OddSearch ()
        {
            cout<<endl<<endl;
            for (int k=1;k<100;k++)
            {
                c=0;
                for (i=0;i<n; i++)
                {

                    if (b[i]==k)
                    {
                        c++;
                    }
                    cout<<b[i]<<"occurs"<<c<<"times"<<endl;
                }
            }
        }
 };

 int main ()
 {
    Array obj;
    obj.input();
    obj.arraySeries();
    obj.OddSearch();

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(int number,int array[],int size){
   int counter=0;
   if(size == 0) return 0;
   if(array[0] == number){
      counter++;
      return counter+count(number,array+1,size-1);
   }    
   return count(number,array+1,size-1);    
 }

int main() {
 
  int array[] = {1,2,2,4,4,8,7,3,4};
  int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);

  printf("%d",count(2,array,size));

  return 0;    
}
```