# Are Sub-Arrays Guaranteed to be Allocated Linearly?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-layout, static-allocation

I know [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38029323/2642059) is in violation of the [`reinterpret_cast` rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) but it also presumes that sub-arrays will be allocated linearly.

I believed this was not guaranteed, but as I search the standard, I find my confidence wavering. If I statically allocate a 2D array, like this:

```
int foo[][4] = { { 5, 7, 8 },
                 { 6, 6 },
                 {},
                 { 5, 6, 8, 9 } };
```

Am I allowed to assume that all elements will be allocated linearly? That is to say that if `foo[0]` is at address 0x00000042, will:

- `foo[1]` be at address 0x00000052
- `foo[2]` be at address 0x00000062
- `foo[3]` be at address 0x00000072

<sub>These addresses are in hex, and yes they are providing space for the 4-element sub-array with `sizeof(int) == 4`; they may and may not be zero-initialized.</sub>

Comment: If `foo[0]` is at address `0x00000042`, `foo[1]` will be at address `0x00000052` only if `sizeof(int)` is `4`. I suspect you assumed that `sizeof(int)` is `4`.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's definitely not a dupe as he `malloc`s the memory in a loop so thee are absolutely no guarantees that can be made about the layout of those sub-arrays in memory.

Comment: @JonathanMee The question is not the same but the answers describe a static 2d array not a dynamically allocated array of pointers.  hence the no close vote from me.

Comment: @RSahu OK I've edited I think that I have all my bases covered...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are Sub-Arrays Guaranteed to be Allocated Linearly?

Yes. Whether the elements of the array are sub-arrays or non-array objects, they are guaranteed to be stored contiguously in memory.

For completeness, here is the standard quote:

> [dcl.array]
>
> 1. [snip] An object of array type contains a **contiguously allocated** non-empty set of N subobjects of type T. [snip]

There is no exception for the case when `T` is an array.

---

> So we know this isn't guaranteed to be the case for `const char[4]`.

On the contrary, we do know that this **is** guaranteed for `char[4]` objects just like it is guaranteed for other types.

> For example: const char first[] = "foo"; char foo[][4] = {"bar", "foo", "", "baz"}

`first` would be stored like this in memory:

```
{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}
```

`foo` would be stored like this:

```
{'b', 'a', 'r', '\0', 'f', 'o', 'o', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', 'b', 'a', 'z', '\0'}
```

> So why would you say this is guaranteed for ints?

It is guaranteed for `int[4]`, `char[4]` and any other type that you can imagine.

Comment: So we know this isn't guaranteed to be the case for `const char[4]`. For example: `const char first[] = "foo"; char foo[][4] = {"bar", "foo", "", "baz"}` So why would you say this is guaranteed for `int`s?

Comment: @JonathanMee, they will be if you use `char foo[][4] = { {'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'}, ...};`.

Comment: @RSahu: They will be even if you use `char foo[][4] = {"bar", "foo", "", "baz"}` -- Not sure why he thinks otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanMee see my edit.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Hmm, I thought that string literals were only ever allocated once by the compiler. Apparently I thought wrong.

Comment: @JonathanMee: They are. But when you initialize a char array with a string literal, the string literal is copied to the array. It is a separate entity from the string literal

Comment: When you don't supply enough initializers for an array, the remainder isn't undefined, it's zero filled. There isn't an exception when a string is used as an initializer, is there?

Comment: @JonathanMee: Wait, did you mean that when you create two string literals with the same value, the compiler gives them the same address? It might do, but that is not a guarantee from the standard. And anyway, that is a separate issue from this, as per my previous comment. That would only be relevant if we were initializing pointers with string literals.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for pointing that out. I don't know why I thought otherwise. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 3):

From the C language standard ISO/IEC 9899 *§6.2.5 Types/p20* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of
>   objects** with a particular member object type, called the element type.

Also from the C language standard ISO/IEC 9899 *§6.5.2.1/p3 Array subscripting* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> Successive subscript operators designate an element of a
>   multidimensional array object. If `E` is an n-dimensional array (n >=
>   2) with dimensions `i x j x . . . x k`, then `E` (used as other than
>   an lvalue) is converted to a pointer to an `(n - 1)`-dimensional array
>   with dimensions `j x . . . x k`. If the unary `*` operator is applied
>   to this pointer explicitly, or implicitly as a result of subscripting,
>   the result is the pointed-to `(n - 1)`-dimensional array, which itself
>   is converted into a pointer if used as other than an lvalue. **It
>   follows from this that arrays are stored in row-major order (last
>   subscript varies fastest).**

From the above we can conclude that a 2D array is actually a 1D array stored in row-major order.

**Consequently, it's safe to assume that elements of a sub-array are stored contiguously in memory**.